# Problems separating GUI from logic

Tags: java, class, user-interface, get, logic

I am currently learning java and wanted to give myself a project that was both challenging and fun. I decided to build a game that I remember playing when I was a kid called dopewars.

This is my second attempt at this game. When I began my first attempt, all went well. After a short while my source code began to fill wildly out of control until I could continue no more as I kept getting lost within mountains of code.

I then decided to begin again, only this time I wanted to seperate the gui from the logic (2 different .java files). This is where my problem lies. Previously this would work fine. Since seperating my java files the functionality has stopped.

When I press jbutton b1, my program is supposed to take the price value of cocaine and the units value entered into the jtextfield by the user, perform a calculation by accessing a method within Buy.java, and then update the appropriate JLabels within the s jpanel of GUI.java.

For example, user x wants to buy cocaine at the price indicated, so he enters a value representing the quantity he would like. He then presses the buy button which ultimately deducts the money from his pocket which is shown on the left side of the program window by using a method within the Buy class.

I hope you can understand my explanation and I hope to hear from you soon. Thanks.in advance. My Source code is below.

Comment: The NSA is all over this one.

Comment: They already stripped the code out!

Comment: Are you saying that you have just two classes or are you packing multiple classes in a single `.java` file?

Comment: Basically, you need to implement a [Observer Pattern](http://www.oodesign.com/observer-pattern.html) which seperates the changes of the model from the UI, so the model has no concept of the UI, but simply makes notifications when something changes which the UI change react to

Comment: I am making 2 .java files

Comment: Im having trouble getting my source code uploaded

Comment: Edit your answer, paste your code as any other text, then apply `{}` formatting.

Comment: *"having trouble getting my source code uploaded"*  What problem *exactly*?  1) For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). 2) Use code formatting for code.  To do that, select the code and click the `{}` button above the messaged posting/editing form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you should make a main.java (with GUI, etc.) and a logic.java (or whatever you want to call it) and make the main class Extend the logic class. to solve your jbutton problem, you should probably make the Main class extend the JFrame class, and implement the ActionListener interface, and then in the ActionPreformed method, call a method to do the logic from the logic class. I hope this helped.